# Expression should be True but it becomes False

Tags: python-3.x, loops

I'm trying to write greater common divider func. But code stops when k is equal 6

```
    def gcdIter(a,b):

    k = min(a,b)
    while(b%k != 0 and a%k != 0):
        k  = k -1

    return k

print(gcdIter(9,12))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have and, so when b % k is not 0 and when a % k is not 0. When k is 6 "a % 6 != 0" is false, and you end up with true and false, which is false.

Instead try to use or.

Comment: Yeah your are right. I wasnt think 12%6's consuquence. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I believe you meant `or` and not `and` in the `while` condition. Since in the first iteration `k` is equal to either `a` or `b`, `and` does not make much sense.

```
def gcdIter(a, b):
    k = min(a, b)
    while b % k != 0 or a % k != 0:
        k = k - 1
    return k

print(gcdIter(9, 12))
# 3
```